# Dealing with Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, fragment

I am looking for some pointers/advice/etc on navigation for my app. The following is a layout of all my screens and the flow between them:

[image: Layout Diagram]

So the main part of this layout I am having trouble understanding how to implement is the the left most navigation drawer button's children. The main screen under the button is really just another screen with a button, and when the button on Main is clicked, it takes you into the wizard like set of screens. On each step you can go back to the previous screen, forward to the next, or by clicking the drawer button it will take you back to main again.

So what I suspect, and this is coming from someone almost entirely new to android, is that I need one activity for main, and then one activity with a set of fragments for each step, correct? Any advice is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DrawerLayout and fragments like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="MainFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FF232323"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:name="NavigationFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Great! And what about the main to individual step screens? Should all of those step screens be one activity broken into multiple fragments?

Comment: [Go read this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). It's a good explanation with samples from the docs